# Add a new node at the begininning of linkedlist in python?

Tags: python

This is my code. I trying to add a new node at the beginning of the linked-list. But the first node should be overwritten. So how should i add a new node without overwrite a first node.
sample output: `10 15 20`
I trying to add 5 at the beginning. It comes like : `5 15 20`
I need a output like this : `5 10 15 20`.

```
def push(self, new_data):
    new_node = Node(new_data)
    new_node.next = self.head
    self.head = new_node

llist.push(5)
```

This is the code in full:

```
class Node: 
    def init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.next = None 

class Linkedlist: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.head = None 
    def printlist(self): 
        temp = self.head 
        while(temp): 
            print temp.data, 
            temp = temp.next 
    def push(self, new_data): 
        new_node = Node(new_data) 
        ew_node.next = self.head 
        self.head = new_node 

if __name == 'main': 
    llist = Linkedlist() 
    llist.head = Node(10) 
    second = Node(15) 
    third = Node(20) 
    llist.push(5) 
    llist.head.next = second 
    second.next = third 
    llist.printlist()
```

Comment: `llist = 5 + llist` ?

Comment: i can't understand what you ask?

Comment: How about you show the rest of your code for `Node`?

Comment: Show us all the code including `Node` and the code that shows the incorrect output.  Best guess is that `self.head` is pointing to the `15` node before the call to `push()`

Comment: This is a singley linked list? That code should work. Can you post a minimal working example? We don't need the full implementation! Yank out unnecessary methods.

Comment: class Node:
 def __init__(self, data):
  self.data = data
  self.next = None 
class Linkedlist:  
 def __init__(self):
  self.head = None  
 def printlist(self):
  temp = self.head
  while(temp):
   print temp.data,
   temp = temp.next  
 def push(self, new_data):
  new_node = Node(new_data)
  new_node.next = self.head
  self.head = new_node  
if __name__ == '__main__':
 llist = Linkedlist()
 llist.head = Node(10)
 second = Node(15)
 third =  Node(20)
 llist.push(5)
 llist.head.next = second
 second.next = third 
 llist.printlist()

Comment: This is my full code

Comment: The problem is now clear and has been solved below.  I suggest you avoid modifying the internals of the data structure externally, I'd suggest making head pseudo-private by renaming it as `self._head` and only manipulating the linked list via your own (correct) `push()` method.

Comment: okk now i understand my mistake. Thanks

Comment: There are other problems with this code, such as `def init__(self, data)` which should be `def __init__(self, data)`, an apparent typo in `ew_node.next = self.head` and a stray comma at the end of the print.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your main program:

```
llist.head.next = second
```

This explicitely sets the list's head to point to the second element (value 15), effectively losing the previous first node (10).

> But the first node should be overwritten.

This part of your question is unclear - your example says the opposite. If you want to *replace* the previous first node, then all you have to do is `self.head = self.head.next` and then push, as you do in `__main__`. However that's not what your example shows.

If on the other hand you want to actually *overwrite* the value of the first node, you could do e.g.:

```
self.head.value = 99
```

> So how should i add a new node without overwrite a first node.

Your code for `push` looks correct. I'm assuming your `self.head` points to the wrong node to begin with. Here's your code embedded in a minimalistic linked list implementation that works. For comparison I'm also adding the `push_replace` method that loses the first element:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class List(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def push(self, new_data):
        # this is your actual code 
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
    def push_replace(self, new_data):
        # replace the previous first node
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head.next
        self.head = new_node
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

l = List()
l.push(20)
l.push(15)
l.push(10)
l.push(5)
list(l)
=> 
[5, 10, 15, 20]
# now loose the first item
l.push_replace(99)
list(l)
=>
[99, 10, 15, 20]
```

Note as @FujiApple has pointed out you should avoid modifying the list from outside the `List` code. In other words, always implement list modification as a new method. This localizes knowledge about how the list works and makes your code more stable and easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little difference in your code you have to use head as a Class Variable where value is shared among all the instances not as the attribute of class. Please refer the code for better understanding. Thank you

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.next = None 

class Linkedlist: 
    head = None
    def __init__(self): 
        pass 
    def printlist(self): 
        temp = Linkedlist.head 
        while(temp): 
            print temp.data, 
            temp = temp.next 
    def push(self, new_data): 
        new_node = Node(new_data) 
        new_node.next = Linkedlist.head 
        Linkedlist.head = new_node 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    llist = Linkedlist() 
    Linkedlist.head = Node(10) 
    second = Node(15) 
    third = Node(20) 
    #llist.push(5) 
    Linkedlist.head.next = second 
    second.next = third 
    llist.printlist()
    llist.push(5)
    print ''
    llist.printlist()
```

OUTPUT:

```
10 15 20 
5 10 15 20
```